# Submit button is inactive when placed in col-4 but form submits in col-8 laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
         <form action="action" method="post">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this submits the form
          </div>
  <div class="col-4">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this is inactive and doesn't submit the form
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

The col tag of bootstrap is working weirdly and the submit buttons are not working in a similar sense.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
     <form action="action" method="post">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this submits the form
      </div>
 <div class="col-4">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this is inactive and doesn't submit the form
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to paste this <form action="action" method="post"> tag before <div class="col-8">

Comment: I tried the same code on my end and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed in your code, you need to paste this `<form action="action" method="post">` tag before `<div class="col-8">`

try this

```
<div class="row">
  <form action="action" method="post">
    <div class="col-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this submits the form
    </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this is inactive and doesn't submit the form
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

html close tag is mistake, **if you want submit button out of `form` but be still a part of the form**, must do like this :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-8">
    <form id="my-form" action="action" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this submits the form
    </form>

</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="my-form">Submit your Post</button>  //this is inactive and doesn't submit the form
</div>
```

I set `id` for form

```
<form id="my-form" action="action" method="post">
```

and then set `form` attribute for button submit :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="my-form">Submit your Post</button>
```

or you can try other way like following:

```
<div class="row">
<form action="action" method="post">

<div class="col-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this submits the form
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your Post</button>  //this is inactive and doesn't submit the form
</div>
</form>
```